# Why is window.open() blocked?

Tags: support, stack-snippets, security

When I run this code from a server, it works just fine, but it doesn't work in a Stack Snippet:

```js
var wind;

function openWindow() {
  wind = window.open("https://www.google.com/", "wind", "width=1000,height=700");
}

function closeWindow() {
  wind.close();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="openWindow()" value='Open'/>
<input type="button" onclick="closeWindow()" value='Close'/>
```

I have configured my browser to allow popups by default.

The log that is generated after trying to open a popup in a snippet is:

> js:17 Blocked opening 'https://www.google.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

Why is `window.open()` blocked in snippets? I am sure there must be a good reason for doing so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Security.

The moment you allow a window from a different domain to open, it gets access to the parent window and details about the parent page and **can change the parent page**.

Comment: Can't you just use `noopener` like you did [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286066/258777)?

Comment: These are not **links**, but an embedded **IFrame**. Different beasts.

Comment: Oh yeah; sorry!

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer is correct. If you attempt to access `window.opener` from a page on another (unsafe) domain, you'll get *Error: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.*. If you attempt to access it from a page on the (safe) same domain, there's nothing to worry about, especially since the Stack Snippet domain doesn't have access to anything sensitive anyway

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Nonetheless something very legitimate like this won't work either

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":button").click(function() {
    html2canvas($("#testdiv"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var win = window.open(myImage);
        if (win) {
          //Browser has allowed it to be opened
          win.focus();
        } else {
          //Browser has blocked it
          alert('Please allow popups for this website');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #2C7CC3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testdiv">
  This is an image
</div>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```