# Stack Snippets don't allow opening new tabs/windows

Tags: discussion, design, stack-snippets

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59433044/9787887) of mine. The code works well on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/am80793v/), but doesn't work on the Stackoverflow's snippet. By "works" I mean I want it to **open https://www.google.com/ on a new tag**, which is what the OP of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59433022/9787887) wants.

I open the console when running on the Stackoverflow snippet and this is the error message:

[image]

Is there any way to make my answer work well even on the Stackoverflow snippet *(which make its demonstration more attractive)*?

```js
document
.querySelectorAll("a.fresh")
.forEach(a => {
  a.setAttribute("target", "_blank")
});
```

```css
a.fresh {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="fresh" href="https://www.google.com/">link1</a>
<a class="fresh" href="https://www.google.com/">link2</a>
```

Comment: There's https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337916/, but I think the top answer there is wrong. If it was *significantly* exploitable, JSFiddle wouldn't be permitting it. That said, wanting to demonstrate opened windows is a very rare situation, and I kind of like being able to depend on Stack Snippets always staying inside their iframe inside the page on Stack Exchange. Allowing opened windows introduces a (marginal) attack vector (for phishing, spam, and NSFW links) which would otherwise require a deliberate click.